# Rack Warden: how can I access the message passed to the fail! method?

Tags: rack, warden

When failing an authentication strategy in Warden, a message can be passed to the `fail!` method. How can I access this message in my default failure application action such that I can display it in a flash message? I tried `request.env['warden'].message`, but after looking at the code for `Warden::Proxy` this variable is only set for winning strategies. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a different way of failing strategies (from recent documentation), is to use `throw(:warden, :foo => 'bar')`. Anything you throw with will be available in your failure application through `request.env['warden.options']`, including a string of the desired url as well. HTH

Answer (score 4):

When using the fail or fail! methods, you can obtain the failure message from the environment warden object.

Example:

```
def unauthenticated
  flash[:alert] = env["warden"].message unless env["warden"].message.blank?
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Proxy#message-instance_method